# Installing extension magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions

when installing an extension in new project without personal template, the extension works very fine but when i tried to install  the same under my project with a pesonal template, this does'nt work. Can you please explain to me the error and how to fix it thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you have installed extension and when you try to add new template in that extension it's not working?

Comment: no i have created a simple tempalte and then added the extension so  the link next sign in (track order ) doesn't appear

Comment: Where you have created template?

Comment: under design /frontend/Magenticians/Mytheme

Comment: if you have added extension , template should be inside namespace/module/view/front/templates directory and it should be defined in appropriate xml connected with controller

Comment: when i acces trackorder/index/index i get 404 error*

Comment: Show me your etc/frontend/route.xml,Controller file and layout file

Comment: now that i created the module under other nema (namespace)  i get the page /trackorder/index/index but the link in the top menu is not there

Comment: write your layout xml code here

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magenticians\Trackorder\Block\TrackOrderLink" name="track-order">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Track Order</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: where you have put this xml i mean file location?

Comment: under layout under view

Comment: check default.xml file in module-customer inside vendor, they have used <referenceBlock name="top.links"> , try that way

Comment: ok thanks a lot brother can you please help me resolve this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243549/not-adding-in-cart-magento-2

Comment: did your issue resolved about header link?

Comment: ok great ,can you vote my answer so that someonw can get help from it in future, i am writing answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check default.xml file in module-customer inside vendor, they have used

```
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
       <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

    </referenceBlock>
```

you can do this way in your xml layout file

Comment: I have already added comment at last

Comment: okey Great   :) .  Please try to ans extach. it will help others.