# Not adding in cart magento 2

Tags: magento2, template

I installed this template http://magento2.flytheme.net/themes/sm_shop4u/default/ and i am facing this error when triyng to add in cart [image]

please help

Comment: Please check your logs or print the error specifically from where the error pops up that can give us the idea of error you are facing.